# Match X or more words in a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have these documents:

```
{ 
  "_id": 1
  "title": "The quick brown fox" 
}
{ 
  "_id": 2
  "title": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" 
}
{ 
  "_id": 3
  "title": "The quick brown fox jumps over the quick dog" 
}
{ 
  "_id": 4
  "title": "Brown fox brown dog" 
}
```

If I query `brown` documents, all the documents will be returned, but I'd like to say "if the query doesn't match with two or more words, it is not a match" or "if the query doesn't match a certain percentage of the sentence, it is not a match".

Right now I'm using the score to address this behavior, but that's kind of tricky. What would be a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Look `minimum_should_match` in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)

Example:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "term": {
                "thread.id": inputQuery 
            }
        }],
        "should": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "subject": inputQuery
                }
            },
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "body": inputQuery
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1    <-- in your case it will be 2
    }
}
```

Comment: But `minimum_should_match` will tell how many should clauses from the bool query need to match in order to the document be a valid match